# Something is writing my htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a web site built with codeigniter, and I installed last year wordpress to have a blog. But since 3 weeks ago the problem began when I tried to access my admin site and appear the codeigniter 404 error. So I realized that the problem was the .htaccess an somehow was written by something. And I think is wordpress, I remove the code that was added and everything was fine, but again the htaccess was written, so I deleted my blog folder that contains all wordpress file and the problem was there again, then I delete the wp_ tables from my Database, but the problem was still there.
The code that has been written is:

```
# BEGIN SYSTEM API

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^al/(.*)$ myfolder/wp-inf.php?$1 [L]

    # END SYSTEM API
```

I searched for the wp-inf.php file and I found something like this:

```
<? eval(base64_decode("ICAgIGVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygwKTsgICRscnUgPSAiZ2c.....")); ?>
```

I don't know what to do or where to find the file that has been writing my htaccess. I have been cleaning and deleting some files, but nothing.

Hope you can help me with this.
Thank you

Edited:******
If I decode what is inside base64_decode appear this:

```
 error_reporting(0);  $lru = "gg/4623696-260514551155404-520n89823525745/765s127r625o9

(edited)

}echo $result; exit; }
```

Comment: Burn your server, start over. Your VPS is infected.

Comment: Your server has been compromised, contact your hosting provider *immediately*.

Comment: yes. .. Contact server admin.

Comment: that sucks. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Well creating a new server and transfering the data wont help because its the files that are writing your htaccess and not an access issue. What you have to do is search all your files for 'base64_decode' and 'eval', and see if these files are default from wordpress or are created and named to confuse for example there is no file called wp-inf.php by default in wordpress. These 2 functions are 90% of the times used for malicious intentions.

- Base64_decode is used to decode any encoded string so that its difficult to read and search for (obfuscate).
- Eval is used to execute any php code thats given to it.

You can use this decoder to decode the actual code and see what the intention was. 
https://www.base64decode.org/

Another way would be to compare your folder structure with the orignal wordpress structure.

**To avoid this in future, try never to use any nulled theme or plugins.**

Comment: There are no indications the OP's issues have anything to do with "nulled" themes or plugins.

Comment: @songdogtech Well someone got into his wordpress didn't he? and we all know that an up to date wordpress system has never been breached. Its always the user's mistake. Secondly i was not impling that he did install a nulled plugin, even though if he did no one cares. But most of the times nulled plugins are the cause for intrusions. There was no reason to down vote the answer, as it was a very strong suggestion to avoid any future mishaps.

Comment: But if someone got into my wordpress, why if I delete all the files of wordpress and delete the tables of the database, the problem stills there?

Comment: Obviously If deleting the wordpress folder is an option then go for it, but if you have valuable data that you dont want to loose then you will have to go through files and get rid of the naughty code. You should also try to find how someone got in, in the first place. I see the code you added, part of it is missing. But what i understand from this code is that, it grabs a page from a url and then uses regex to extract links from that page instead. So you can think of it like a search engine bot but with malicious intent. Some code and urls are missing in this file, try searching for suka-test